# Editing keys of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare the keys of two dictionaries in Python. The problem is that in one dictionary, the name of the key is `'key1'` and in the other is `'key1   345'`, that is there is a number after a tab character. Of course Python cannot match the keys, I was wondering if there is any way to just remove the tab character and the number?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a dictionary or a file? Your question isn't clear. Also, what have you tried? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` to split the keys at any whitespace and `[0]` to get the first segment. Use a dict comprehension to create a new dict with those trimmed keys.

```
>>> d = {"key1\t234": "foo", "key2\t678": "bar"}
>>> {k.split()[0]: v for k, v in d.items()}
{'key1': 'foo', 'key2': 'bar'}
```

Or, if you want to modify the dictionary in-place, you can try something like this:

```
>>> for k in d:
...     d[k.split()[0]] = d.pop(k)
>>> d
{'key1': 'foo', 'key2': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is still a way to match them;

```
In [1]: 'key1' in 'key1   345'
Out[1]: True
```

And while you cannot edit a string (strings in Python are immutable) you can remove the old key/value pair and put in a new one.

```
In [2]: d = {'a': 'eggs', 'key1   345': 'spam'}

In [4]: d['key1   345']
Out[4]: 'spam'

In [5]: d['key1'] = d['key1   345']

In [6]: d
Out[6]: {'a': 'eggs', 'key1': 'spam', 'key1   345': 'spam'}

In [7]: del d['key1   345']

In [8]: d
Out[8]: {'a': 'eggs', 'key1': 'spam'}
```

Comment: Assuming that there is no key like `k` or `y1` or `23`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say name of key in otherfile , u can remove the tab character and the nuber using split()

```
otherName = 'key1   345'
otherName = otherName.split()[0]
print otherName
```